# Unique constraint setting default in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, unique-constraint

I have been trying to make a table where all integer values have by definition 0, but it doesn't seem to work. I tried to make a constraint and enden up like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename]
ADD CONSTRAINT minimum_level UNIQUE
(col_1,col_2,...)
DEFAULT 0 FOR *
```

but it doesn't seem to work on the "defaut" part. Does someone know how to make this?

Comment: You must use correct syntax. [ALTER TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue, can I add a unique constraint on a column which is already having a default constraint?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand. The DEFAULT constraint looks something like:

```
ALTER TABLE ... 
    ADD CONSTRAINT ... DEFAULT 0 FOR col_1
    ADD CONSTRAINT ... DEFAULT 0 FOR col_2
    ...
```

Not sure if multiple constraints are supported, if not it can be split to several statements. What are you trying to achieve with the unique constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Create your table script and then drop it.

In script use DEFAULT keyword for giving default value.

i.e.

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Sandnes'
)
```

While adding we can not define default value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName
ADD DEFAULT 0 FOR ColumnName
```